# Angular2 eventEmitter, parent wont catch it

Tags: angular, eventemitter

Have used quite some time now, trying to find out why the parent does not receive the event and call the function.

Have a parent app (called AppComponent) and the child component (called HomeComponent)

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'home-component',
providers: [],
moduleId: module.id,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
directives: [BannerComponent],
})

export class HomeComponent {

    @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    products: Array<Product> = [];

    isProductSelected: boolean = false;

    constructor(public productService: ProductService) {


    }

    addProductToBasket(product: Product) {

        // Add product to basket.
        this.productService.addProduct(product);
        this.isProductSelected = true;

        if (this.isProductSelected) {
            console.log("Event has been emittet");
            this.selected.emit(this.isProductSelected);

            //Sets to default
            this.isProductSelected = false;
        }   

    }

}
```

I want to notify the parent component, when a product has been added to the basket. Have checked console, and can see that the line **console.log("Event has been emittet");** is being called, so it should send the event.

**AppComponent.html**

```
<aside class="aside" [ngClass]="{'aside-active': isClassVisible }">
     <div class="basket_products" *ngFor="#product of products">


    </div>
</aside>

<router-outlet (selected)="selected($event)"></router-outlet>
```

Here I'm using the ngFor, after I have tried to use the **(selected)="selected($event)"** which should call the method in the AppComponent.ts

**AppComponent.ts**

```
 selected(selected: boolean) 
 {
    console.log("Event catches");

    if (selected) {

        // Get new data
        this.totalProducts = this.productService.getTotalProducts();
        this.totalprice = this.productService.getTotalProductPrice();
        this.shippingPrice = this.productService.getShippingPrice();
    }
}
```

Problem is that the method is never called.

Have tried to follow the step "Parent listens for child event" you see here [Angluar2 interactions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent):

Does anyone here, sees what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't really make sense

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeComponent {

    @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Either it is a component, then it needs a `@Component(...)` decorator instead of the `@Injectable()` decorator.

If it is a service then it can't have an `@Output()`

If it actually is a component then you only can listen on this component

```
<home-component (selected)="selected($event)"></home-component>
```

not on an arbitrary element. This doesn't listen to the `@Output() selected ...`

```
 <div class="basket_products" *ngFor="#product of products" (selected)="selected($event)">
```

except when `HomeComponent` has a selector like `selector: '.basket_products'`

Comment: Its a component.. sorry for the confuse.

Comment: please remove the `@Injectable()` from the component. You only need it for services but not when other decorators like `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()` are already there. These decorators include `@Injectable()`

Comment: Okay, done that. I'm not really following what you are trying to tell me. 

Right now I'm using routes, and loading the home component like:

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: I try to tell you to fix issues with your code. It doesb't mean that thos definitely solves your problem but I don't want to waste my enetgy looking for subtle issues before the obvoous ones are fixed ;-)

Comment: Have added and updated my code. As  you see, I'm using the router-outlet, but the parent appComponent still can't catch the event.

Comment: You can only listen to the `(select)` from your `@Output() select ...` on `<home-component (select)=...>`. Events from outputs don't bubble.

Comment: You also can't listen on `<router-outlet>`. You need a shared service to communicate with components added by the router.